# yo angular generator error phantomjs install

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, phantomjs, yo

I have tried installing `yo anugular` and got below error, I have tried updating `node`, `npm`, `npm cache clean` etc. but its not working.

When I ran `$ yo angular` it goes and fetch dependencies using `bower` but its gives this error and move on

```
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.31: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.0"})
...

> phantomjs@1.9.15 install 

/Users/jhondoe/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Downloading https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip
Saving to /var/folders/vy/sc6v8frj4d3gprgzdpfcjhkm0000gn/T/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.9.8-macosx.zip
Receiving...
npm ERR! Darwin 13.0.0---------------------] 37% 0.0s|
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.0

npm ERR! null == true
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
  [=======================================-] 98% 0.0s
Received 9187K total.
Extracting zip contents
```

and after that on more error and some warning

```
npm WARN unmet dependency /Users/jhondoe/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-jshint/node_modules/jshint/node_modules/cli/node_modules/glob requires minimatch@'0.3' but will load
```

and error

```
> pngquant-bin@2.0.3 postinstall 

/Users/jhondoe/Desktop/webapp/node_modules/grunt-contrib-imagemin/node_modules/imagemin/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/pngquant-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/jhondoe/Desktop/webapp/npm-debug.log
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'pako/lib/zlib/messages'
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'pako/lib/zlib/messages'
```

after that it fails saying below msg

```
Loading "cssmin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'pako/lib/zlib/messages'
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'pako/lib/zlib/messages'

...
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/Users/jhondoe/Desktop/webapp/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket jYytgLM38t_yiNPOWqbq with id 15305149
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X): Executed 2 of 2 SUCCESS (0.004 secs / 0.02 secs)
Warning: Task "cssmin" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I am banging my head from 6 hrs, please help how can i fix it.

my Node version is `v0.12.0` NPM is `2.5.0` and `OSX 10.9`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, it was the version issue of node, see the warning

```
npm WARN engine karma@0.12.31: wanted: {"node":"~0.8 || ~0.10"} (current: {"node":"0.12.0","npm":"2.5.0"})
```

Downgrading `Node` to `0.10.30` fixed the issue

I have posted this answer so that other people can resolve there similar problem.